# ASP.NET web forms baffling postback behaviour

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I created a small script to preserve the focused element during an async postback, and it works perfectly fine *except* when tabbing through controls generated inside an asp:Repeater, where a *full postback* is triggered for some mysterious reason. Here's a concise sample to work with:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script runat="server">
        public IEnumerable<int> Measurements_GetData()
        {
            return new[] { 123, 328, 1099 };
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <h1>OK</h1>
                <div>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Measurement1" runat="server" Text="123" AutoPostBack="true"  />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="328" AutoPostBack="true" />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text="1099" AutoPostBack="true" />
                </div>

                <h1>Not OK</h1>
                <asp:Repeater ID="Measurements" runat="server" SelectMethod="Measurements_GetData" ItemType="System.Int32">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <div>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Measurement" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text="<%# Item %>" />
                    </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            var focusedElementId = "";
            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

            prm.add_pageLoaded(function (source, args) {
                // re-focus element, if any selected prior to postback
                if (focusedElementId !== "") {
                    document.getElementById(focusedElementId).focus();
                    console.log("focus:" + focusedElementId);
                }
            });

            prm.add_pageLoading(function (source, args) {
                var fe = document.activeElement;
                focusedElementId = fe !== null ? fe.id : "";
            });
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This sample shows both the working and the non-working behaviour. If you click the first text box, change the value, tab to the next, change the value, tab to the next, it correctly preserves focus on the last element, and you can see the progression of preserved focused elements in the JS console.

Now if you watch the JS console and click on the first text input in the repeater generated markup (Not OK section), change then tab, change then tab again, you can see focus is lost on the last control because a full postback is triggered (JS console is cleared).

What is going on here? This looks like it must be a web forms bug, I can't make sense of it otherwise. If it is a bug, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, this is a known problem in ASP.NET web forms. It's caused by the ClientIDMode changes in ASP.NET 4.0. MS posted [some workarounds here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3118973/web-forms-async-postback-from-repeater-controls-performs-incorrect-full-postback).

If you don't care about the generated IDs of controls, the simplest solution appears to be [reverting to pre-ASP.NET 4.0 behaviour by setting](https://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770142):

```
<pages ClientIDMode="AutoID" /
```

in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like a bug, but your JavaScript function is somehow the cause of the PostBack. If you remove it completely the TextBoxes behave as they should. There is probably a mismatch between the TextBoxes bound by your script (which is only fired when the page is first loaded) and the ones that are re-generated inside the Repeater after an async postback.

If you register all the TextBoxes for Async PostBack, they will work again.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Measurements.Items)
    {
        TextBox tb = item.FindControl("Measurement") as TextBox;
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(tb);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course it works without the script, that's the point of this question. I don't bind any text boxes in JS or do anything special. The page_Loading event fires when the async reply is received, the id of the currently focused element is saved, the page_Loaded event then fires (*not* just on first load as you claimed), at which point focus is restored by looking up the element by id and calling focus(). I don't cache anything, I always look up controls by id. There's nothing special going on here, it's an absurdly simple script. Thanks for the workaround, but how exactly is this not a bug?